# Why isn't there current in R2 when capacitor is not fully charged

Tags: electric-circuits, electrical-resistance, capacitance

[image]

If we consider the switch to be closed, why would there be no current in R2. My understanding is that, as the current flows it will split into two at the junction, thus having a current charging C and another one going through R2.

I would appreciate an explanation to better understand this problem, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

R2 and C are connected in parallel, therefore the voltage across R2 is equal to the voltage across C. If the capacitor is initially uncharged, then the initial voltage across R2 is 0. Once the switch is closed, the capacitor begins charging and the current through R2 starts increasing, in direct proportion to the charge on C.

Answer (score 0):

The moment the switch is closed, the potential difference across capacitor, and thus across the R2 is 0 and and thus no current flows. However, the very next moment the current begins to flow.

If we consider switch to be closed, i.e., battery is now connection to the circuit, definitely, there will be current through R2. Because, there is potential difference between two terminal of R2 - in this case it is equal to the potential difference across capacitor plates.

Comment: Perhaps the question is referring to the *instant* the switch is closed.  You are of course correct for any t > 0.

Answer (score 0):

In the beginning, there will be current in R2 as the capacitor gets charged. But even after a long time, ALL the current will flow through R2 as the capacitor will be fully charged.